# Bold serif headings in beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, bold

I'm trying to get the same effect as `\usefonttheme{structure bold}`, but with a serif font.

That is, (frame)titles in serif bold, other fonts serif regular.
Unfortunately this does not seem to work:

```
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\fontfamily{serif}, series=\bfseries}
```

The title stays regular.
How can I create bold serif headings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this solution work for you?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries,parent=structure}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries,parent=structure}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test}
        Test
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]